# Python: TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable, conflict with ugettext?

Tags: python, django, unicode, typeerror

I am using the `GeoDjango` example with the [class `WorldBorder`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/). 
My trouble is that I can't print out the name of the selected countries. When I try to execute

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
...
location = fromstr(... , srid=4326)
country = WorldBorder.objects.get(mpoly__intersects=location)
print _('User country determined to %s') %country.name
```

i get the error message:

```
Python: TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

When I remove the `ugettext_lazy`, everything works fine. **How can I keep the translation option and make the string work?**

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of your error? What does `print repr(_)` give you, at the point of the exception?

Comment: Django never threw a full traceback since everything was captured by an `except`. Removing the exception for testing revealed, that the GeoDjango class wasn't imported. Pathetic mistake. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Right, the lesson is then: don't use blanked `except` clauses! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using a Python shell. There, _ will take the value of the last expression evaluated. So _ ends up being the WorldBorder instance after your third line. To avoid this problem, when you're playing with translate in a shell, alias ugettext_lazy to something other than '_'.